# How to set another class as property of a TComponent's descendant class

Tags: delphi, properties, object-inspector

I'm defining my first components and I would like they can be configured using a TMyOptions class instance.

```
TMyCmp = class(TComponent)
protected
  FMyOptions : TMyOptions;
  ...
published
  property MyOptions : TMyOptions read FMyOptions write FMyOptions;
  ...
end;
```

Each component, in the constructor, creates an instance of TMyOptions that's defined like this example:

```
TMyOptions = class
protected
   FMyOption1 : boolean;
   FMyOption2 : boolean;
published
   property MyOption1 : boolean read FMyOption1 write FMyOption2;
   property MyOption2 : boolean read FMyOption2 write FMyOption2; 
end;
```

So, in the object inspector I can see TMyOptions but I can't change values.
Could someone tell me which is the right way to achieve my goal?
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Your property setter for `MyOptions` is no good. You need a setter method that assigns the state of the new value to the value owned by the `TMyCmp` instance. Which means `TMyOptions` derives from `TPersistent` and overrides `Assign`. Remy's answer at the dupe has all this detail. Start there.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for your willingness!